# How to align three divs containing radio inputs

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in a form that accept radio buttons as input. Currently with my css it looks like this:
[Please see this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBK84.png)

```
                                    O Text      O Text      O Text
                                O Text      O Text&Text O Text
                                        O Text      O Text
```

How can I edit my css to make it so that the radio buttons are vertically aligned AND the whole set of radio inputs center aligned , something like this:

```
                                    O Text      O Text        O Text
                                    O Text      O Text&Text   O Text
                                    O Text      O Text
```

This is the code I have

Thank you!

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="material" class="text-light">Text</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="plastic" name="material" value="Plastic">
                <label for="plastic" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="cans" name="material" value="Cans">
                <label for="cans" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="paper" name="material" value="Paper">
                <label for="paper" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="relationship" class="text-light">Text</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="school" name="relationship" value="School">
                <label for="school" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="family" name="relationship" value="Friends &amp; Family">
                <label for="family" class="radio-label">TextText</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" id="company" name="relationship" value="Company">
                <label for="company" class="radio-label">Company</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="frequency" class="text-light">Type</label>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="Repeating" value="Repeating">
                <label for="Repeating" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="One-Time" value="One-Time">
                <label for="One-Time" class="radio-label">Text</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS that you have currently?

Comment: `<label for="material"` - which input is this supposed to relate to? Same for `<label for="relationship"` and `<label for="frequency"` - these appear to relate by name to an input within the `DIV` element where another label relates to the same `input` element

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap these form-groups in a container, you can set that container to `display: flex` which will allow you to use flexbox properties to align your form groups as needed.

```html
<div class="radio-container">
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend id="material" class="text-light">Text</legend>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="plastic" name="material" value="Plastic">
    <label for="plastic" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="cans" name="material" value="Cans">
    <label for="cans" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="paper" name="material" value="Paper">
    <label for="paper" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend id="relationship" class="text-light">Text</legend>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="school" name="relationship" value="School">
    <label for="school" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="family" name="relationship" value="Friends &amp; Family">
    <label for="family" class="radio-label">TextText</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" id="company" name="relationship" value="Company">
    <label for="company" class="radio-label">Company</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend id="frequency" class="text-light">Type</legend>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="Repeating" value="Repeating">
    <label for="Repeating" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="One-Time" value="One-Time">
    <label for="One-Time" class="radio-label">Text</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
  
</div>
```

```css
.radio-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I modified the HTML based on Professor Abronsius' comment. The Prof is correct that those extra labels make the HTML invalid. Assuming they are group headers of some kind, I made a judgement call and added fieldsets/legends to the form-groups.

Comment: Do you mean a container for each form group or one container for ALL the form-groups?

Comment: Good question. One container for all the form groups.

Comment: what are fieldsets?

Comment: Also @Jeff that just put all the form-groups into ONE row

Comment: Sometimes when you have a form with a lot of sections, you may want to break it up into pieces using semantic tags. Forms have a tag called fieldset, which has a tag called legend. These are like "section" and "header" but for forms where you think it's appropriate. -- Also, I added another property to center the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` along with a `width:Xpx` to create aligned rows. Then `justify-content: center;` on the whole flex container to center it. If you want the title label text to align with the radio label text you can set the radios to absolute postion and put a common padding on all labels

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.radio.inline {
  width: 100px;
}

label {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="material" class="text-light">Text</label>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="plastic" name="material" value="Plastic">
      <label for="plastic" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="cans" name="material" value="Cans">
      <label for="cans" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="paper" name="material" value="Paper">
      <label for="paper" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="relationship" class="text-light">Text</label>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="school" name="relationship" value="School">
      <label for="school" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="family" name="relationship" value="Friends &amp; Family">
      <label for="family" class="radio-label">TextText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" id="company" name="relationship" value="Company">
      <label for="company" class="radio-label">Company</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="frequency" class="text-light">Type</label>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="Repeating" value="Repeating">
      <label for="Repeating" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" class="freq" name="frequency" id="One-Time" value="One-Time">
      <label for="One-Time" class="radio-label">Text</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can I somehow get the label in the row of the radio buttons?

Comment: It is in the row. Do you mean you want the text of the header label to be inline with the text next to the radio buttons?

Comment: thanks but I think I wasn't clear. What I want is the header label and the radio inputs to be in one ROW, right now they are in one COLUMN. So the format I'm looking at is:
Header_Label        OLabel     OLabel    OLabel